# google タグの使用は適切でしょうか？

Tags: 討議, タグ

[google](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google)タグが存在しますが、wiki説明も特に記載されておらず、"質問を絞り込む"という意味では現状だとあまり有用な割り当てがされていないように見受けられます。

**よく見かけるタグ付け例：**

- [google](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) + [api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api)など
  代わりに[google-api](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api)や、より詳しい`google-XXX-api`等の形式でタグを割り当てるべき。
- [google](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google) + [google-maps](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)など
  一緒に割り当てたタグで説明は十分で、[google](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google)は質問を絞り込む役目を果たしていない。
  ([python](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)に対して一緒に、より大局的な[プログラミング言語](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%9f%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e)と付けるようなもの)

なお、参考までに英語版SOでは

- googleタグは存在しません
- apiタグも存在するけど非推奨 ("より適切なタグを割り当てるのが望ましい"と説明あり)

以上を踏まえて、スタックオーバーフローでは[google](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google)タグを今後どのように扱うのがベストでしょうか？

Comment: なんとなくタグの質問を眺めていましたが、ほとんどgoogleタグの意味をなさないもので置き換え可能かなと思って「廃止で」回答しようと思いましたが、[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/7386)に関してはgoogleタグが合っているなと思いました。なにか別タグを付けられますかね？

Comment: 英語版SOを参考にするなら、`google-search`や`search-engine`が該当するかもしれません。